# Is it possible to use class methods from Windows.Devices.WiFi.dll in golang?

Tags: windows, go, dll, wifi

In the [example](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/?GOOS=windows#example_LoadLibrary)
 in the documentation for package syscall uses the [GetVersion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getversion) function from the kernel32.dll library.

Is it possible to use class methods from the [Windows.Devices.WiFi.dll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.wifi) library in this way?
For example, the [WiFiAdapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.wifi.wifiadapter) class has a [FindAllAdaptersAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.wifi.wifiadapter.findalladaptersasync) method.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {
    h, err := syscall.LoadLibrary("Windows.Devices.WiFi.dll")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("LoadLibrary: %v\n", err)
    }
    defer syscall.FreeLibrary(h)

    proc, err := syscall.GetProcAddress(h, "WiFiAdapter.FindAllAdaptersAsync")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("GetProcAddress: %v\n", err)
    }
    r, _, _ := syscall.Syscall(uintptr(proc), 0, 0, 0, 0)
    fmt.Println(r)
}
```

Otput:

```
LoadLibrary: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: That's `C#` which is different. You should search msdn for `C` functions.

Comment: If your language supports COM then the answer is yes, it is possible. WinRT API is just a COM classes.